# Backup of Folder on Server

Tags: windows

We have Windows Server 2008 installed. We need to take backup of folder from a desktop on LAN. The Folder is not shared. Is there any tool or software or   Schedule can be made which should automatically take the backup of that folder date-wise & make a copy on server?

Can we do it through the "Schedule Tasks option"? The desktops have Windows   Vista/Window 7.

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! This question does not seem to be about security, but about backups. I beileve it should be migrated to our sister site [SU]. However, asking for tool recommendations is off-topic both on this site and on [SU]; I suggest you remove that from your question. Good luck!

Comment: Which folder is not shared? The desktop or the server one?

Comment: Cross posting is undesireable on Stack Exchange.  This is a cross-posted question that was bounced back here, so now you have two identical questions.  Please delete this one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [UrBackup](http://www.urbackup.org/), which is extremely powerful and nice for Backup to server solutions!